# Is there the full list of return codes for "wusa.exe"?

Tags: windows-update

Is there the full list of return codes for "wusa.exe"?

I guess that Windows System Error Codes are applicable here.
http://www.hiteksoftware.com/knowledge/articles/049.htm

But sometimes I need to consider other return codes such as: 2359302 or 2359303

Comment: http://viewrz.com/video/google-it - I'm being serious.  Use `wusa.exe #errorcode` in your google search and you'll get better results for actions then using a simple list of return codes.

Comment: Sometimes patch admins get really obscure error codes or error codes that are common with something completely unrelated, and google doesn't provide good links to those cases

Comment: https://cloudywindows.io/windowsinstallererrorcodes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't pretend that these pages are comprehensive, but here are links to two documents that might help:

- [*Windows Update error code list*](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/938205)
- [*Windows Update Agent Success and Error Codes*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh968413(v=vs.85).aspx)

Hopefully they're useful. There's a third document titled *Windows Update Agent Networking Error Codes* that you'll find along side *Windows Update Agent Success and Error Codes*. I would have included that link but a I received a red tooltip that informed me I "need at least 10 reputation to post more than 2 links."

Comment: Keep in mind that some error codes have to be converted from base10 to hex, eg. code 2359303 in `Windows update  could not be uninstalled because of error 2359303 "" (Command line: "wusa  /uninstall /kb:3098779 /quiet /norestart")` equals 0x00240007

Comment: It appears some error codes show in the event log in their decimal form. We kept seeing the error code 2149842976‬ in event viewer with almost nothing coming up on google. Convert this to its HEX as 0x80240020 and voila. its there in both those articles. this was super misleading. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a link (I hope it is what your are searching for): http://inetexplorer.mvps.org/archive/windows_update_codes.htm .

Comment: I have no idea why this was downvoted, but this list is just what I needed. For example, searching for error code 0x8024017 will give you various forum threads and blog posts about that "problem". This list will just tell you, that it means an update is not needed.

Comment: It was probably downvoted because if the link goes dead or the information becomes invalid, it decreases the value of the answer, since the answer can't stand on its own without the contents of the link.

Comment: Link returns 404

Comment: See http://web.archive.org/web/20150821142343/http://inetexplorer.mvps.org/archive/windows_update_codes.htm for the archived version.

Answer (score 3):

Wusa.exe is just a wrapper for Windows Update functions to install MSU updates. Install the [Windows 10 SDK](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk) and look into the file `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\um\wuerror.h"` to all Windows Update related errors.